# Unable to call Pageable methods in JUnit test classes

Tags: java, junit, pagination

Shown below is the code snippet that checks for previous and next pages of a Page of vendors from the repository.When writing `JUnit` for this method

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException  at
>   org.springframework.data.domain.Unpaged.getPageNumber(Unpaged.java:87)

is thrown from the third line while calling the `getPageNumber()` method.

Please help me to resolve this.

```
 PageDTO pageDTO = new PageDTO();
                int totalPages = vendors.getTotalPages() - 1;
                if (totalPages - vendors.getPageable().getPageNumber() != 0) {
                    pageDTO.setNext(paginationUrl + "getvendorslist?start=" + 
                 vendors.getPageable().next().getPageNumber() + "&limit=" + limit);
                } else {
                    pageDTO.setNext("");
                }
                if (vendors.getPageable().hasPrevious()) {
                    pageDTO.setPrevious(paginationUrl + "getvendorslist?start=" + vendors.getPageable().previousOrFirst().getPageNumber() + "&limit=" + limit);
                } else {
                    pageDTO.setPrevious("");
                }

    }
```

**This is how I have given the test case**

```
    @Test
    public void findAllVendors() {
        VendorAddress address = new VendorAddress(1, "address", "city", "country", "kerala", "zip", "craeted",
                "modified", true, false);
        ContactInformation contactInfo = new ContactInformation(1, "firstName", "lastName", "nayana.a@thinkpalm.com",
                "createdBy", "modifiedBy", true, false);
        PaymentDetails payDet = new PaymentDetails((long) 1, "mode", true, false, (long) 3);
        List<PaymentDetails> paymentDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        paymentDetails.add(new PaymentDetails((long) 1, "Cash", true, false, (long) 1));
        List<VendorDetails> details = new ArrayList<VendorDetails>();
        details.add(new VendorDetails((long) 1, "2", "TXA445", "pass", "createdby", "modifiedby", true, false, address,
                contactInfo, address, paymentDetails));
        Page<VendorDetails> vendors = new PageImpl(details);
        PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0, 50);
        Mockito.when(vendorDetailsRepository.findAllVendors(page)).thenReturn(vendors);
        ResponseModel responseModel = registrationService.findAllVendors(0, 50);
        Integer result = responseModel.getCode();
        assertEquals((Integer) 1000, result);


    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Can you provide signature of this method: `vendorDetailsRepository.findAllVendors(page)`. Also please provide full code of the method being tested and stacktrace

Comment: @Query("select v from VendorDetails v where v.isDeleted=false and v.isActive=true")
Page<VendorDetails> findAllVendors(@Param("page") PageRequest page);
 This is the method in the repository.Using this page of vendors i have to give the response of pagination.